# ubuntu 20.4 Composer and laravel by termail error

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

im was  try to installion  composer and laravel in os ubuntu 20.4  , try do  Composer upgrade
any one  know how fixed in this or has The solution ?

```
➜  ~ laravel -V                                     
zsh: permission denied: /home/bushido/.config/composer/vendor/bin
➜  ~ ls -l $HOME/.zshrc                             
-rw-r--r-- 1 bushido bushido 4092 May 25 11:32 /home/bushido/.zshrc
➜  ~ ls -l /home/bushido/.config/composer/vendor/bin

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 bushido bushido 32 May 19 11:36 laravel -> ../laravel/installer/bin/laravel
➜  ~
```

thank you all i appreciate to help me

Comment: How to fix what? Please share more details about your problem, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Where is the command you use to Upgrade the Composer ?

you should, go to the folder you download the Composer File,
run

```
sudo php composer.phar update
```

use Sudo to avoid the issue pf Permission Denied,
like

```
 sudo laravel -v // The Command is to check Laravel Version
```

Comment: hello  thank you for replay this  one 
Composer version 2.0.14 2021-05-21 17:03:37  im was last one  try intsall Using version ^4.2 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been updated